# git/macos: checkout of png images fails

Tags: git, macos, png

**SETUP:**

- MacOS/intel
- git version 2.23.0

**ACTION:**

```
git checkout my_branch
```

to checkout a repository that contains a list of PNG files. Surfing the repository (BitBucket) at the according places shows, that the PNG images are all present.

**EFFECT:**

The files checked out contain the names of the PNG files in the repository, but their content is plain text, namely something like the following:

```
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:c0ffeebabaa...f00d
size 3031
```

**QUESTION:**

What can be done here?

Other people, checking out from Windows computers, also, get the PNG files.

I removed the `./git/index` file and `git reset`. But that did not help.

I removed the repository completely and cloned it again. But that did not help.

Comment: This indicates that whoever built the repository used Git-LFS, not Git.

Comment: Indeed, I just found out. If you make this an answer, I give you a check mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @torek, the problem arises from cloning a repository with `git` while the `lfs` plugin is not installed.

To fix this install `git-lfs`, for example with `brew`,

```
> brew install git-lfs
```

enter the repositories directory and type

```
> git lfs install
```

Possibly, you might have to delete the repository and clone it again.